# Symfony Forms dropdown customization

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony Forms to let a user select an *Entity* from my database. Displayed, I want to have this *Entity*'s name and description, where the latter is greyed out and italicized. How can I do this, avoiding the use of additional JavaScript?

Currently, I construct the form as follows:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('activity', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Entity',
            'class' => Entity::class,
            'choice_label' => function (Entity $e) {
                  return $e->getName() . ' - ' . $e->getDescription();
            }
        ])
    ;
}
```

resulting in the following dropdown:

[image: current imp]
[image]

I found that you can [render each form option manually](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html), but`<option></option>` tag does not allow children tags.

Comment: You can not do that with a normal select field, you'll need a custom replacement than (and that means JS again.)